# Kendo UI && JavaScript - Display "YES" and "NO"

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How can I achieve this. I got '**y**' and '**n**' data that fetch from my database.
But in the grid I wanted to display "**YES**" and "**NO**". Need to display in "**segmentActive**" column.

```
        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        dataBound: onDataBound,
        height:400,
        sortable: true,

        columns: [ 
            { field: "segmentActive", title:"STATUS", width: "50px", editor: RadioSegmentActive },
            { field: "marketSegmentName", title:"SEGMENT NAME", width: "180px" },
            { field: "publicPrice", title:"PUBLIC PRICE", width: "50px", editor: RadioPublicPrice },
            { field: "isHouseUse", title:"HOUSE USE", width: "50px", editor: RadioHouseUse},
            { command: ["edit"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "30px" },
        ],
        editable: "inline",
        //....
```

Plus I also got another function in editor for radio button for the add and edit purpose.

```
function RadioSegmentActive(container, options) {
var guid = kendo.guid();

    $('<input class="k-radio" id="radio3" name="segmentActive" type="radio" value="y" >').appendTo(container);
    $('<label class="k-radio-label" for="radio3">YES</label>').appendTo(container);  //YES
    $('<br>').appendTo(container); 
    $('<input class="k-radio" id="radio4" name="segmentActive" type="radio" value="n" >').appendTo(container);
    $('<label class="k-radio-label" for="radio4">NO</label>').appendTo(container);  //NO    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that you can use the [template](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview) property.

It accepts a function that receives the rows data. The string you return will be displayed.

**ES6:**

```
{ field: "segmentActive", ... template: data => data.segmentActive == "y" ? "YES" : "NO"  }
```

**Non ES6:**

```
function displaySegmentActive(data){
    return data.segmentActive == "y" ? "YES" : "NO"
}

...

{ field: "segmentActive", ... template: displaySegmentActive }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dude! Merry Christmas and Happy New Year!